# T-SQL and SSRS multi parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a question about querying SQL from SSRS multi-value parameter.
My multi-value parameter is basically empty and depending on user-entered value so it is empty by default:

I try to make SQL query to query all data if no value is provided to the SSRS parameter and query only the data of the parameter if it is provided.

I tried these and none works so far:

1. `SerialNumber IN (IIF(@SNList='', SerialNumber, @SNList)`
2. `SerialNumber IN (IIF(@SNList IS NULL, SerialNumber, @SNList)`
3. `SerialNumber IN (@SNList)`

**#1** works as I wanted to return all if the parameter is empty & if only one value is entered for the parameter but return an error if I entered more than 1 value (well, because when there are more than 1 value, we cannot use "=")

**#2** will not return anything if no value is entered for parameter & if only one value is entered for the parameter but return an error if I entered more than 1 value.

**#3** Works for multi/single values parameter

Is there a way to check number of values for the parameter or is there another way to make this works?

Comment: Are you sure that `SerialNumber IN (@SNList)` works the way you think it does? If SSRS is passing `@SNList` as a string like `'1,2'` and you would expect it to match a row for each serial number 1 and 2, then I would check that again. It would only work if you've simplified the problem here and you're actually embedding that comma-separated string in dynamic SQL.

Comment: Unfortunately SSRS teaches the poor syntax `IN(@SomeScalarVariable)` would equate to `IN(1,2,3,4,5)`, @AaronBertrand . SSRS instead injects a usuable list into the `IN` and removes the variable itself. People then think that that's how T-SQL works where actually it's SSRS that is teaching flawed syntax. More frustratingly SSRS doesn't support Table Type Parameters, despite being part of the SQL Server Suite...

Comment: @Larnu Oh, gross.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-select parameters cannot be null, and to apply multi-select parameters SSRS will transform your query which would break if you tried to examine the variable in TSQL.

What you *can* do is introduce a second TSQL parameter that you set based on whether you should apply the main parameter.  So your multi-select parameter @p1 is a string with a default value of "All", dataset query would be something like

```
if @p1IsNull = 1
begin
  select *
  from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
end
else
begin
  select *
  from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
  where SalesOrderId in (@p1)
end
```

And @piIsNull is set with an expression

[image]

of the form

```
=iif( Parameters!p1.Value(0) = "All", 1, 0)
```

Depending on the parameter values, the SQL query will look like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'if @p1IsNull = 1
begin
  select *
  from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
end
else
begin
  select *
  from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
  where SalesOrderId in (N''43660'',N''43667'')
end',N'@p1IsNull int',@p1IsNull=0
```

or like this

```
exec sp_executesql N'if @p1IsNull = 1
begin
  select *
  from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
end
else
begin
  select *
  from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
  where SalesOrderId in (@p1)
end',N'@p1IsNull int,@p1 nvarchar(3)',@p1IsNull=1,@p1=N'All'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, David! It works. :)
I added the query parameter to my SQL query and having the WHERE clause to "WHERE    (@SNnull = 0 AND a.SerialNumber IN(@SNList)) OR (@SNnull = 1 AND a.SerialNumber IN (a.SerialNumber))" and it works. You are saviour :)